# Simple use of 'tail' and 'grep'. Multiple conditions

Tags: bash, cygwin, grep, logging

I'm trying to read a log file which is being written to by a simple daemon. I would like to filter my "live" output to certain - multiple - "types".

My types are: `DEBUG|INFO|WARN|ERROR|FATAL`

This is what I have so far, and it works for one case, but I cannot get it working for multiple cases though.

```
tail -f log.txt | grep INFO
```

I've tried a couple of things to try and say I want "`WARN`'s & `ERROR`'s", but nothing is really working for me. How would I correct this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try:

```
tail -f log.txt | egrep 'WARN|ERROR'
```

Comment: +1 `grep -E` also works.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to switching to `egrep`/`grep -E` to get the alternation operator of extended regular expressions, you can you can also use multiple `-e` arguments to regular `grep` or even `fgrep`/`grep -F`

In fact, if your searches are all static strings (like the original question), you can even ‘downgrade’ all the way to `fgrep`/`grep -F` which might give a speed boost (since it always does direct string comparisons without regexps).

```
fgrep -e DEBUG -e INFO -e WARN -e ERROR -e FATAL
```

Also POSIX allows patterns to be separated by newlines.

```
# bash-ish to put a newlines into the string
fgrep $'DEBUG\nINFO\nWARN\nERROR\nFATAL'

# Standard syntax, but easier to break while editing(?):
fgrep "$(for f in DEBUG INFO WARN ERROR FATAL; do echo "$f"; done)"
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works (regular `grep` and escape the pipe character):

```
tail -f log.txt | grep 'WARN\|ERROR'
```

Comment: That is a GNU extension to the syntax of basic regular expressions, it probably won't work for non-GNU greps. It is more portable to use `egrep` or `grep -E` and the non-escaped alternation marker (pipe).