# Writing "tail -f" output to another file

Tags: bash, cygwin, grep, logging

As a continuation from [my last post](https://superuser.com/questions/59471/simple-use-of-tail-grep-multiple-conditions) where I have used `grep & tail -f` to find occurences of "rare" events.  I would like to record this in another file.

I've tried turning

```
tail -f log.txt | egrep 'WARN|ERROR'
```

into

```
tail -f log.txt | egrep 'WARN|ERROR' | tee filtered_output.txt
```

The file gets created, but nothing is populated, is this a caching issue or otherwise? How would I get a real-time appending of my tail's output to a new file?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Buffering is the problem.

Do it this way,

```
tail -f log.txt | egrep --line-buffered 'WARN|ERROR' | tee filtered_output.txt
#                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Confirmed to work on Cygwin too.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably a buffering issue.  See this [SO post on disabling the auto-buffering when using pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000674/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe).  You can use the `unbuffer` command from `expect`:

```
$ unbuffer tail -f log.txt | egrep 'WARN|ERROR' | tee filtered_output.txt
```

**Edit**: Since you have a longer pipeline, you probably need to unbuffer each command (except the last):

```
$ unbuffer tail -f log.txt | unbuffer egrep 'WARN|ERROR' | tee filtered_output.txt
```

**Edit 2**: `unbuffer` is available on Cygwin from the `expect` source package (eg [expect-20030128-1-src.tar.bz2](http://cygwin.elite-systems.org/release-2/expect/), found in the `expect/examples` folder), but it's a very short script.  If you have the `expect` package already installed, simply put this into a script called `unbuffer` in your `/usr/local/bin` directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
# Description: unbuffer stdout of a program
# Author: Don Libes, NIST

eval spawn -noecho $argv
set timeout -1
expect
```

On Debian, the `unbuffer` command is provided in the `expect-dev` package and is installed as `expect_unbuffer`.

Comment: is there a way to accomplish this with cygwin?

Comment: added info on using in cygwin; you'll need the `expect` package.

Comment: Thanks, can't try until Monday now sadly.  Will update then.

Answer (score 4):

*When using a command that does not really 'finish' (such as `tail -f`), this actually does not really work or that well (at all).*

> You should be able to redirect the output to a text file. Try this:
>
> ```
> tail -f log.txt | egrep 'WARN|ERROR' > filtered_output.txt
> ```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

This is the version of `unbuffer` that I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
# Description: unbuffer stdout of a program
# Author: Don Libes, NIST

if {[string compare [lindex $argv 0] "-p"] == 0} {
    # pipeline
    set stty_init "-echo"
    eval spawn -noecho [lrange $argv 1 end]
    close_on_eof -i $user_spawn_id 0
    interact {
    eof {
        # flush remaining output from child
        expect -timeout 1 -re .+
        return
    }
    }
} else {
    set stty_init "-opost"
    set timeout -1
    eval spawn -noecho $argv
    expect
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks for the additional info.  dunno if it's cygwin-friendly but it looks like a more intelligent script.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you can use the `unbuffer` utility from Expect.

Note, however, that depending on your system and available version of Expect, you may need to use the `-p` switch to unbuffer. Citing the man page:

```
   Normally, unbuffer does not read from stdin.  This simplifies use of unbuffer in some situations.  To use unbuffer in a  pipeline,  use
   the -p flag.  Example:

           process1 | unbuffer -p process2 | process3
```

So you might need this invocation:

```
unbuffer -p tail -f log.txt | unbuffer -p egrep 'WARN|ERROR' | tee filtered_output.txt
```

BTW, see this article for thorough explanation of the output buffering problem: http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/