# Filter tail command through multiple grep commands to separate files

Tags: linux, bash, grep, tail

What I am trying to do is filter the output of one log file into separated log files based on a grep filter.

> tail -f test.log | tee >(grep "Error" > error.log) >(grep "Warning"" >
>   warning.log)

This way all "Error" entries are in one file, and all "Warning" entries are in a separate file.

I know this works in concept, because if I use *cat* instead of *tail*, I get the correct file output, but cannot track changes in real time (which I need because I am watching output logs from actively running tests)

Also, if I remove the '>' file re-directors from the *grep* commands it outputs the individual grep outputs to the console correctly; however, I want a recorded file as well.

**Answer:**

When writing to a file the output of *grep* was being buffered.  Using *egrep* with a *--line-buffer* option fixed the behavior.

The new command looks like:

> tail -f test.log | tee >(egrep --line-buffered "ERROR" > error.log) >(egrep --line-buffered "WARNING" > warning.log)

Comment: Could be a lineBuffer problem in tailf. Please check: http://superuser.com/questions/59497/writing-tail-f-output-to-another-file

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier if you use more than one line to do this. You could write a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -f test.log | while read line; do
    if echo "$line" | grep -q "Error"; then
        echo "$line" >> error.log
    elif echo "$line" | grep -q "Warning"; then
        echo "$line" >> warning.log
    # The following is in case you want to print out lines that do not match 
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done
```

Comment: My next step was to create a Python program to do what I want, since I would get much more flexibility out of it that way.  I wanted to understand why a command that looked like it _should_ work, wasn't.  Turns out it was buffering.

Answer (score 0):

@Ryan, thanks for posting an answer to your question.
another (universal) way to set per-line buffering is to use `stdbuf` command:

```
tail -f test.log | tee >(stdbuf -oL grep "ERROR" > error.log) >(stdbuf -oL grep "WARNING" > warning.log)
```

here is an excerpt from `man stdbuf`:

```
SYNOPSIS
   stdbuf OPTION... COMMAND
...
   -o, --output=MODE
          adjust standard output stream buffering
...
   If MODE is 'L' the corresponding stream will be line buffered.
....
EXAMPLES
   tail -f access.log | stdbuf -oL cut -d ' ' -f1 | uniq
   This will immedidately display unique entries from access.log
```