# Shell unbuffering for CygWin: is it possible?

Tags: shell, cygwin, buffer

I have tested on CygWin doing "ls -R" with a **large directory** and sending the **output to a `Test.txt` file**, so the process takes about 30 seconds to complete; the file is created, but it is **empty**; it will only be filled when the "ls -R" command **finishes**, and I need to see the file content meanwhile new data is entering.

The problem is supposed to come from the **buffering** that the operating system makes before writing into the file.

This is what I have tested in order to write into the file without buffering:

- The **unbuffer** command from the `expect` package: where is it? Modern `expect` version has no such `unbuffer` command (see below):

```
    ./unbuffer -p ls /cygdrive/y/Repositorio/ -R > Test.txt
    ./unbuffer ls /cygdrive/y/Repositorio/ -R | tee Test.txt
    ./unbuffer -p ls /cygdrive/y/Repositorio/ -R | tee Test.txt
    ./unbuffer ls /cygdrive/y/Repositorio/ -R | ./unbuffer -p egrep "" | tee Test.txt
    ./unbuffer -p ls /cygdrive/y/Repositorio/ -R | ./unbuffer -p egrep "" | tee Test.txt
```

- Installing the **Expect** package and naming "unbuffer" this script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect --
    # Description: unbuffer stdout of a program
    # Author: Don Libes, NIST
    eval spawn -noecho $argv
    set timeout -1
    expect
```

- Installing the **Expect** package and naming "unbuffer" this other script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect --
    # Description: unbuffer stdout of a program
    # Author: Don Libes, NIST
    if {[string compare [lindex $argv 0] "-p"] == 0} {
        # pipeline
        set stty_init "-echo"
        eval spawn -noecho [lrange $argv 1 end]
        close_on_eof -i $user_spawn_id 0
        interact {
        eof {
            # flush remaining output from child
            expect -timeout 1 -re .+
            return
        }
        }
    } else {
        set stty_init "-opost"
        set timeout -1
        eval spawn -noecho $argv
        expect
    }
```

- The **script** command:

```
    script -c "ls /cygdrive/y/Repositorio/ -R" | tee Test.txt
    script -c "ls /cygdrive/y/Repositorio/ -R" /dev/null | tee Test.txt
    script -q -c "ls /cygdrive/y/Repositorio/ -R" /dev/null | tee Test.txt
    script -q -c "ls /cygdrive/y/Repositorio/ -R" /dev/null | grep "" --line-buffered | tee Test.txt
    script -q -c "ls /cygdrive/y/Repositorio/ -R" /dev/null | egrep "" --line-buffered | tee Test.txt
```

- The **egrep** command with unbuffering option:

```
    cat BigFile.txt | egrep "" --line-buffered | tee Test.txt
```

- The **stdbuf**: it does not exist on modern CygWin, or so I think.
- Another methods:

```
    ls /cygdrive/y/Repositorio/ -R 1>&2 | tee Test.txt
    ls /cygdrive/y/Repositorio/ -R 1>&2 |& tee Test.txt
```

- Tests done with `bash` and `mintty`.
- Checked and tested everything in **these threads**:

  [Writing "tail -f" output to another file](https://superuser.com/questions/59497/writing-tail-f-output-to-another-file)
  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe
  https://serverfault.com/questions/294218/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-without-buffering-on-unix-linux

Results are always the same: the output file `Test.txt` is only filled at the end of the "ls -R" command.

Any more ideas, please?

Comment: I'm not sure this is solely due to buffering. Buffers nowadays are usually 64 kb and 30 seconds is a long time; I'd expect `ls` to fill 64 kb faster than that. If this is still an issue for you, could you tell us the size of the resulting `Test.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

Use stdbuf.  It is on cygwin in the coreutils package.