# Read serial output, remove nul and save to file

Tags: bash, terminal, cygwin

In Cygwin, I am trying to read serial port input, filter it to remove nul characters, and save the output to a file.  Something like the following, which results in an empty logfile:

```
cat /dev/ttyS1 | tr -d '\000' >myfile.log
```

This shows stdout on the terminal:

```
cat /dev/ttyS1 | tr -d '\000'
```

I tried using `stdbuf -oL -eL`, per [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/59497/writing-tail-f-output-to-another-file), to no avail.

**Bonus points** if you can get it to work with grep filtering stdout on the terminal (i.e., log everything to file, but only see filtered output on the terminal).

```
cat /dev/ttyS1 | tr -d '\000' | tee myfile.log | egrep --line-buffered "WARN|ERROR"
```

Note: The serial port I am using is an FTDI USB serial adapter.

Comment: Does `/dev/ttyS1` exist ?

Comment: I used `/dev/ttyS1` as an example. The serial port I'm using on this particular machine is different and does exist (I can read input using `cat /dev/ttyS1`).

Comment: If `cat /dev/ttyS1`works and `cat /dev/ttyS1 | tr -d '\000'` produces nothing it seems your serial port is only producing null

Comment: @matzeri No, it is producing regular text with nulls inserted before "\r\n" on each line. I think it might be due to the source of the serial data is written in C, which uses null terminators for strings. But lets assume I don't have control over that.  How do I remove the nulls and save to file?

Comment: Does work if you split the  action in two : `cat /dev/ttyS1 > tempfile` and `cat tempfile | tr -d '\000' ` ?

Comment: Yes, that is my current approach that works.  It's puzzling that doing it all together in a single pipe-chain does something different.

Comment: Very strange. Testing with `cat /dev/random | tee -a file1 | tr -d '\000' > file2` file1 has null bytes but file2, as expected none. `od -b file2 | colrm 1 7 |  grep 000` is empty

Comment: Using `/dev/random` in cygwin produces the filtered output correctly, as I would expect.  However, `/dev/ttyS1` still results in a 0-byte file after the `tr` call.